# My application won't run saying 'XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException' at bean declaration code inside spring-secuirty.xml file,

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, web, spring-security

I'm a newbie to Spring framework. I started learning spring with its 3.1 version. Right now I"m experimenting with spring security. After I setup the configuration for spring security, my application is NOT being deployed and throws some wild errors. 
"Line 30 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid;"
The 30th line declares a bean with id = 'myUserDetailsService'.

Apart from spring-security I've another xml spring-config file which stores controllers and view resolvers.

This is what I've attempted so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  > 
 ...

<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
        <init-param>  
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>  
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    </servlet> 
  <!-- Dispatcher servlet mapping to start page  -->

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/Zlog</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
<!-- SOME FILTERS DEFINED HERE  -->
 <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>        
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener> 
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

..
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

   <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Zlog.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="any"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https"/>
        <form-login login-page="/Zlog" default-target-url="/stwebLanding.spr"
            always-use-default-target='true' 
            authentication-failure-url="/noAccessStweb.jsp" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/Zlogout.jsp" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    </http>
<authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
    </authentication-manager>

     <bean id="myUserDetailsService"      class="com.ssmb.stweb.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" >
    </bean> 

</beans:beans>
```

Application-Context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="checkoutSetupBO" class="com.ssmb.stweb.bo.CheckoutSetupBO" >    
    </bean>    

    <bean id="checkoutGroupCodeBO" class="com.ssmb.stweb.bo.CheckoutGroupCodeBO" >
    </bean>  

    <bean id="checkoutScriptCodeBO" class="com.ssmb.stweb.bo.CheckoutScriptCodeBO" >
    </bean>  

    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.ssmb.stweb.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" >
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

'myUserDetailsService is a bean object which refers to a class which implements spring security's UserDetailsService interface. 
Console:

```
[11/26/13 16:17:46:670 IST] 0000001b webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor]: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 30 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1649)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:745)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:633)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:422)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1134)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1369)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:638)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1632)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.access$400(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$3.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1567)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5277)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5493)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl._startModule(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1596)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1334)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.startDeployment(StartDeploymentTask.java:236)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.fineGrainUpdate(StartDeploymentTask.java:187)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.StartDeploymentTask.performTask(StartDeploymentTask.java:99)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor$ExpandApp.expand(AppBinaryProcessor.java:1539)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.sync.AppBinaryProcessor.postProcessSynchronousExt(AppBinaryProcessor.java:701)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.postProcess(BLABinaryProcessor.java:575)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.bla.sync.BLABinaryProcessor.onChangeCompletion(BLABinaryProcessor.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.postNotify(FileRepository.java:1936)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.FileRepository.update(FileRepository.java:1445)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.repository.client.LocalConfigRepositoryClient.update(LocalConfigRepositoryClient.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.update(WorkSpaceMasterRepositoryAdapter.java:657)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.update(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1998)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.RepositoryContextImpl.synch(RepositoryContextImpl.java:1946)
    at com.ibm.ws.sm.workspace.impl.WorkSpaceImpl.synch(WorkSpaceImpl.java:549)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.configservice.ConfigServiceImpl.save(ConfigServiceImpl.java:717)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor13.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1334)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.remote.AdminServiceForwarder.invoke(AdminServiceForwarder.java:334)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1438)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$200(RMIConnectionImpl.java:83)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1276)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1371)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:799)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:750)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi._RMIConnectionImpl_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectionImpl_Tie.java:158)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:626)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:479)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:514)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2880)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2753)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1648)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 95 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `spring-security.xml` file, change this

```
<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.ssmb.stweb.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" >
</bean>
```

to this:

```
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.ssmb.stweb.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" >
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Lotof Thanks!Now my app is deployed.But instead of showing the landing page, its stuck up at the first filter my apps calls. So landing page URL is reloaded again and again and will result in a page not found error.URL:http://example.com/Start_page/Start_page/Start_page/Start_page/Start_page/Start_.

Comment: @user3036265 you are welcome. If my answer was helpful, you can consider accepting it. And the URL you have given is not working here. You can consider asking a new question for the problem that you are facing now.